# Why a custom dependency property is not animated by a DoubleAnimation?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, dependency-properties

I have the following WPF window:

```
<Window x:Class="AnimationTest.MainWindow"
    x:Name="main"

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >

<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" x:Key="animationStoryboard" TargetName="main" TargetProperty="CurrentOffset" >
        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:5"  SpeedRatio=".8" AutoReverse="True" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

With the following code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace AnimationTest
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static DependencyProperty CurrentOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentOffset", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnCurrentOffsetPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnCurrentOffsetPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow control = (MainWindow)d;
    }

    public double CurrentOffset
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)base.GetValue(MainWindow.CurrentOffsetProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hit");
            base.SetValue(MainWindow.CurrentOffsetProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ((Storyboard)base.FindResource("animationStoryboard")).Begin(this);
    }
}
}
```

I expected to have the CurrentOffset property continuosly called but nothing happens. It's like the animation won't start. Anyone can point me where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well AFAIK the property definition in your file for a DP is never invoked by the framework and it only serves as a helper for you when accessing the DP in your code behind. So your MessageBox.Show() will not get invoked by the underlying WPF system even if the animation ran fine. Have you tried checking the value of the DP after the animation finishes to check it's stored value?

Comment: See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) for an explanation of what Viv said (and move the `MessageBox.Show()` call to the `OnCurrentOffsetPropertyChanged` method to see that the animation works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to my previous comment and @Clemens

Just tried your code myself and it works fine. You'll ofc have to "do work" in the `PropertyChanged` handler but the DP works as expected.

I modified your storyboard to not repeat to test the DP value such as:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="animationStoryboard"
            TargetProperty="CurrentOffset"
            TargetName="main">
  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:5"
                    From="0"
                    SpeedRatio=".8"
                    To="100" />
</Storyboard>
```

and the code-behind:

```
public MainWindow() {
  InitializeComponent();
  var sb = ((Storyboard)base.FindResource("animationStoryboard"));
  sb.Completed += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show(CurrentOffset.ToString());
  sb.Begin();
}
```

`MessageBox` was invoked with a value of 99.8888... which looks like it's pretty much working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The properties you wrote as a wrapper for your DependencyProperty will not be called by WPF. It will go directly to your DependencyObject. You can pass a callback to the DependencyObject registration as you did, that *should* be called. You may want to debug there.